# Assign value in all rows following satisfaction of first instance in R

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe with a set of numeric observations (Value) per grouping variable (ID).  I'm looking for an elegant way to do the following in a new column per grouping variable (ID): if Value is -40 or lower, assign a value of 1 starting from the row that *follows* the first instance of reaching -40 or lower.  Every Value preceding the -40 or lower (and including that first instance of -40 or lower) should be assigned something other than a 1 (i.e., assign 0).

Example data:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | Order | Value |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |   -40 |
|  1 |     2 |    32 |
|  1 |     3 |   -59 |
|  1 |     4 |   -35 |
|  2 |     1 |    47 |
|  2 |     2 |    14 |
|  2 |     3 |     0 |
|  3 |     1 |    10 |
|  3 |     2 |    63 |
|  3 |     3 |   -32 |
|  3 |     4 |   -46 |
|  3 |     5 |   -27 |
|  3 |     6 |   -42 |
|  3 |     7 |    45 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

I am looking for something to accomplish this (below):

```
+----+-------+-------+-------------+
| ID | Order | Value | After_Neg40 |
+----+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 |     1 |    32 |           0 |
|  1 |     2 |   -40 |           0 |
|  1 |     3 |   -59 |           1 |
|  1 |     4 |   -35 |           1 |
|  2 |     1 |    47 |           0 |
|  2 |     2 |    14 |           0 |
|  2 |     3 |     0 |           0 |
|  3 |     1 |    10 |           0 |
|  3 |     2 |    63 |           0 |    
|  3 |     3 |   -32 |           0 |
|  3 |     4 |   -46 |           0 |
|  3 |     5 |   -27 |           1 |
|  3 |     6 |   -42 |           1 |
|  3 |     7 |    45 |           1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I tried searching for this type of problem on SO without much luck, but I also had a hard time knowing how to describe this type of problem (maybe it has already been answered, but my search terms may not have uncovered it).  If you have any elegant ways to solve this, I would appreciate your help.  Thanks!

Comment: Try `yourdf$After_Neg40 <- c(0, ifelse(yourdf$Value <= -40, 1, 0)[1:nrow(yourdf)-1])`. Would be easier to help if you posted `dput(yourdf)`.

Comment: Though, reviewing your requested output should the final three values in `After_Neg40` be 1-0-1 instead of 1-1-1? I can't reconcile 1-1-1 with your description.

Comment: Hi, @Zach.  Thanks for your input!  To clarify, the final three values in After_Neg40 should all be 1s.  Basically, I want to turn everything into a value of 1 following the first instance >= -40 is achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`, assuming that the data is in a data frame `df`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, After_Neg40:=ifelse(!is.na(the.row <- which(Value <= -40)[1]) & (1:.N) > the.row,1,0), by=ID][]
##    ID Order Value After_Neg40
## 1:  1     2    32           0
## 2:  1     1   -40           0
## 3:  1     3   -59           1
## 4:  1     4   -35           1
## 5:  2     1    47           0
## 6:  2     2    14           0
## 7:  2     3     0           0
## 8:  3     1    10           0
## 9:  3     2    63           0
##10:  3     3   -32           0
##11:  3     4   -46           0
##12:  3     5   -27           1
##13:  3     6   -42           1
##14:  3     7    45           1
```

The logic is:

1. Find the first row for `which` `Value` is less than or equal to `40` using `which(Value <= -40)[1]`. Set this to `the.row`.
2. If there are no rows for which this condition is true for a group by `ID`, then `the.row` will return `NA`, so we check that with `is.na`.
3. So, if there is such a `the.row` (i.e., `is.na` returns `FALSE`) and for those rows that are greater than `the.row`, set the value to `1`, else `0`. Do this with an `ifelse`.

The result matches your posted desired output, but uses the following data, which switches the first two rows of your posted input data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Order = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), Value = c(32L, -40L, -59L, -35L, 47L, 14L, 
0L, 10L, 63L, -32L, -46L, -27L, -42L, 45L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Order", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L
))
##   ID Order Value
##1   1     2    32
##2   1     1   -40
##3   1     3   -59
##4   1     4   -35
##5   2     1    47
##6   2     2    14
##7   2     3     0
##8   3     1    10
##9   3     2    63
##10  3     3   -32
##11  3     4   -46
##12  3     5   -27
##13  3     6   -42
##14  3     7    45
```

Comment: Thank you, @aichao!  It works!  I especially appreciate your breakdown of the logic (very helpful for someone who has not used this type of logic in R code before).